# $z^2 -3$ in homogenous coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis

I want an expression for $f= z^{2}-3$ in homogenous coordinates ($z_0:z_1$) in the same $\mathbb{P}^1$

**Hint:** Write $f$ as quotient of a homogenous polynomial with the same degree. Use $\mathbb{C}= \{(1:z)|z\in\mathbb{C} \} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{1}(\mathbb{C})$ with $z=z_1/z_0$ and at $\infty$ you can write $w=1/z=z_0/z_1$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have tried to get something in form of \begin{align*} \frac{az_1+bz_0}{cz_1+dz_0}\end{align*}. For the linear case thats clear, but for polynomials I come not furhter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $z = z_1/z_0$ we get $f(z_0,z_1) = (z_1/z_0)^2 - 3$. Since we are in $\Bbb P^1$ we can multiply by $z_0^2$ and get $f(z_0,z_1) = z_1^2 - 3z_0^2$ which is indeed homogenous.

Comment: Quit easy, but do you mean $f(z_0,z_1) = z_1^2-3z_0^2$ ?

Comment: Yes sorry ! ${{}}$